# Mains supply to replace 6 AA batteries

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I would like to replace a battery pack with a power supply.  I have several Force Fx light savers.  These are powered by 6 AA batteries concealed in the hilt.

I want to create a small power supply that will be enclosed in a wall mount for the light sabre, when the sober is on the wall mount the idea is that it will be mains powered.

I would also like to create a small circuit that detects if the power supply is mains or battery and switches out the sound fx when powered from the mains.

The question is, what sort of power supply would I required to replace the 6 AA batteries?

Comment: A 9 V wall wart or similar would do fine. You do however need to provide a schematic for that “switches out the sound fx”.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a professional software engineer and no more than a hobbyist when it comes to electronics...At the moment I have no clue how I'm going to do the sound switching, I would use a relay to switch it out but I'm not sure how to do the detection of mains.  I also want to house the 9v mains supply inside the wall mount.

Comment: Please start your replies with @ and the username. No spaces. In that case, all you need is a diode and a normally closed relay with 9 Vdc coil.

Comment: Light saber battles... in a galaxy far far away... well only as long as the cord.

Comment: @RonBeyer, I have 3 of them and I'd like to turn them into a wall display :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should solve your problems.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKgzux.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thank you thats excellent.  I take it the Magic thing is the light sabre hilt?

Comment: Correct. You are welcome!

Comment: Would one of these be a good fit for this application?  I'm thinking maybe I could run all 3 light savers of one supply? https://www.amazon.co.uk/Guitar-Pedal-Power-Supply-Overcurrent/dp/B06XPG8B71/ref=sr_1_19_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1523518832&sr=8-19-spons&keywords=9v+power+supply&psc=1

Comment: Most likley yes. The 9 V relay will be the hard part to find. 5 V is common as well as 12 V. 9 V isn’t. If you only plan on handcrafting one single contraption like this, I would suggest trying various 12 V relays until you find one which is happy at 9 V.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/ProTechTrader-9vdc-volt-Relay-Non-Polarized/dp/B01JD35LXU/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1523519181&sr=8-5&keywords=9v+relay  not that cheap but looks ok.

Comment: Perfect! Job done!

Comment: what type of diode is that in series with the supply and batteries?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75891/discussion-between-winny-and-splatten).